# hive orc writer.close() return null pointer exception when running on windos

Tags: java, apache, hadoop

I am creating the orc file and adding row to the file. its working on linux. But its not working on the windows.writer.close() return NPE.
    please find the code below and stack trace below and give me help on the same.
    code:--
    package com.testing;

```
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.Arrays;

import org.apache.hadoop.conf.Configuration;
import org.apache.hadoop.fs.Path;
import org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.io.orc.OrcFile;
import org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.io.orc.OrcFile.WriterOptions;
import org.apache.hadoop.hive.serde2.objectinspector.ObjectInspector;
import org.apache.hadoop.hive.serde2.typeinfo.TypeInfo;
import org.apache.hadoop.hive.serde2.typeinfo.TypeInfoUtils;
import org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.io.orc.OrcFile;
import org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.io.orc.OrcFile.WriterOptions;
import org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.io.orc.Writer;


public class Typical  {

    public static void main(String args[]){
        String filePath ="C:/usr/tmp/EDMS_FILE_ARCHIVE_.orc";
        TypeInfo typeInfo=TypeInfoUtils.getTypeInfoFromTypeString("struct<a:string>");
          ObjectInspector inspector=TypeInfoUtils.getStandardJavaObjectInspectorFromTypeInfo(typeInfo);
          WriterOptions options=OrcFile.writerOptions(new Configuration()).inspector(inspector);
          //Path path=new Path(temporaryFolder.getRoot().getCanonicalPath(),"part-00000");
          Writer writer;
        try {
            writer = OrcFile.createWriter(new Path(filePath),options);
             writer.addRow(Arrays.asList("hello"));
              writer.close();

        } catch (IllegalArgumentException | IOException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

    }

}


statcktrace:--

Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException
    at java.lang.ProcessBuilder.start(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.hadoop.util.Shell.runCommand(Shell.java:482)
    at org.apache.hadoop.util.Shell.run(Shell.java:455)
    at org.apache.hadoop.util.Shell$ShellCommandExecutor.execute(Shell.java:715)
    at org.apache.hadoop.util.Shell.execCommand(Shell.java:808)
    at org.apache.hadoop.util.Shell.execCommand(Shell.java:791)
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.RawLocalFileSystem.setPermission(RawLocalFileSystem.java:656)
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FilterFileSystem.setPermission(FilterFileSystem.java:490)
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.ChecksumFileSystem.create(ChecksumFileSystem.java:462)
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.ChecksumFileSystem.create(ChecksumFileSystem.java:428)
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem.create(FileSystem.java:908)
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem.create(FileSystem.java:889)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.io.orc.WriterImpl.getStream(WriterImpl.java:1967)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.io.orc.WriterImpl.flushStripe(WriterImpl.java:1984)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.io.orc.WriterImpl.close(WriterImpl.java:2289)
    at com.testing.Typical.main(Typical.java:30)


Advance Thanks
Hanuman
```

Answer (score 1):

Its an issue with using orc library on windows and writing to local file:

```
java.lang.NullPointerException
at java.lang.ProcessBuilder.start(Unknown Source)
```

Program wants to execute chmod command but its not present on windows - here you get the NPE.
I found workaround which i don't like:

- dowload winutils.exe
- System.setProperty("hadoop.home.dir", "c:\path\to\winutils"); the real path to wintutils libs should be c:\path\to\winutils\bin